# python v3.7 help on dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I"m stuck on this problem when i tested the test cases and kept getting KeyError, is there another way to fix it? 
All of the files are in the shared google drive.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OqrHxY42Cka9_H9pfA9VLQOkIuqoSQKN?usp=sharing

Code:

```
import csv
def read_votes(filename):
        rows = []
        columns = []

        try: 
                with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                        csvreader = csv.reader(file)
                        column = next(csvreader)
                        for row in csvreader:
                                row.append(row)
                dict{}
                vote_dbase = {}
                for row in rows:
                        state = row[0]
                        candidate = (row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]) 
                        if int(row[3]) > 0:
                                if state in vote_dbase:
                                        flag = 0
                                        for i in range(len(vote_dbase[state])):
                                                if row[1] < vote_dbase[state][i][0]:
                                                        vote_dbase[state].insert(i, candidate)
                                                        flag = 1
                                                        break
                                        if flag == 0:
                                                vote_dbase[state].append(candidate)
                                else:
                                        vote_dbase[state] = [candidate]

                return vote_dbase
        except:
                return False
```

[Fail case with KeyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4cER.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code what behaviour you want to occur, as we can't see the tests where the error occurs.

That said, doing some basic debugging, it seems you're not processing the input values properly. The problem is at

```
for row in csvreader:
    row.append(row)
```

You are appending `row` to itself rather than your list `rows`. I think you want

```
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
```

I would also recommend against putting everything in a try block and not doing anything with the exception. This means you can hit an error and you won't get the error message which would help you debug your code. Either don't use the try block or do something like this for the exception block:

```
except Exception as exception_instance:
    print(exception_instance)
    return False
```

There's also a random `dict{}` in your code which doesn't work.